# URL processing in .net Standard 2.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0, system.web

I have a .net library (.net 4.6.1) which I would like to port to the [.net Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/). I already tested it (on a windows box) and it seemed to work without problems.
However in this library I have some functions which use the `System.Web.HttpUtility` for parsing query strings and encoding and decoding query string values.

My question is, what are the consequences of this reference to `System.Web`?  Would it work on a linux server when used from.net core and asp.net core 2 (probably with a performance penalty because of the sheer size of system.web)?

Which package should be used alternatively for URL processing (if possible one from Microsoft)?

Answer (score 0):

For Encoding and Decoding, it seems, that

```
System.Net.WebUtility
```

is the way to go. It encodes and decodes URL and Html-values. For the query string parsing I'm still on the search.

**(for asp.net core)**
With asp.net core >=v2, the [QueryHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_WebUtilities_QueryHelpers_ParseQuery_System_String_)-type can be used (but this gives not help to the question)